# Loop of sprintf only outputing final looped value

Tags: c

I have an char* array. I loop through the correct index of the array to put numbers.

However, it seems that the value placed in the index is wrong. It seems to only store the last call to sprintf.

For instance, if I want the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3. However, it seems to return 3, 3, 3, 3.

I have placed a printf statement to see if there is an error, but it produces the correct numbers. I assume there must be a weird error when using sprintf with an array.

```
char* printArray[12];

for (int i = 1; i < 12+1; i++) {
    char *printVal;
    char temp[10];
    sprintf(temp, "%d", i-1);
    printVal = temp;
    printf("%s\n", printVal);
    printArray[i-1] = printVal;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", printArray[i]);
}
```

This is a simplified version. This produces the error.
I have attempted to use strcpy but that results in the same error.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. How is `printArray` declared?

Comment: You have to copy the data from `temp` into printArray using something like `strcpy`, simple assigning like you do just assigns the pointer value, not the string. Or probably easier just `sprintf` into the `printArray` directly.

Comment: ```printArray = printVal``` doesn't copy the memory contents of ```printVal``` to ```printArray```. It only copies the pointer, such that they both now point to the same address. Is that what you want?

Comment: You do not show your attempt at printing. But 99% it has undefined behavior. Show your MRE ( [mre] ) to allow explaining how.

Comment: This is one of the first things you should have learned about strings, you have to use `strcpy()` rather than `=` to assign them.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Look at this: https://godbolt.org/z/fzb4hz4W1 Do you notice something? Also: https://godbolt.org/z/5eE59xqxb `temp` is *local*.

Comment: @Barmar that results in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the memory for `temp` goes away when you leave each iteration of the `for` loop, so you can't save pointers to `temp` into `printArray`.

You need to make a dynamic copy of `temp` so you can save it outside the loop.

`printArray` should be an array of strings, not pointers, then you can use `strcpy()` to copy them.

```
char *printArray[12];

for (int i = 1; i < 12+1; i++) {
    char temp[10];
    sprintf(temp, "%d", i-1);
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    printArray[i-1] = strdup(temp);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", printArray[i]);
}
```

If you don't have `strdup()` available, it's simple:

```
char *my_strdup(const char *s) {
    char *new = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    if (new) {
        strcpy(new, s);
    }
    return new;
}
```

Comment: Note: Creating own `char *strdup(char *s)` goes against Future library directions including "Function names that begin with str, mem, or wcs and a lowercase letter may be added to the declarations in the <string.h> header".  Better as `my_strdup()` for ones own code.  Also the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strdup.html) function uses `const char *s`.

Answer (score 0):

**Undefined behavior (UB)**

`printArray[i-1] = printVal;` repeatedly assigns the address of local object `char temp[10];`.

Later code attempts to print the data in this common, now invalid, address: result UB.

---

Instead of copying a pointer, copy the contents into memory.

```
// char* printArray[12];
#define INT_STRING_SIZE 12
char printArray[12][INT_STRING_SIZE];

...

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  snprintf(printArray[i], sizeof printArray[i], "%d", i);
}
```

If code must remain as `char* printArray[12];`, allocate memory.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  char temp[INT_STRING_SIZE];
  int len = snprintf(temp, sizeof temp, "%d", i);
  printArray[i] = malloc(len + 1);
  // Check for allocation omitted brevity.
  memcpy(printArray[i], temp, len + 1);
  // or 
  strcpy(printArray[i], temp);
}
```

And free the memory when done.